# Generating HTML to place two tables side by side from PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to have two tables (both ordered by a different column) presented next to each other in a HTML table. Trying with:

```
 <tbody>
   <td>
     <?php
        require_once "db_data.php";
        $bids_results = $mysqli->query("SELECT bid_volume, bid FROM apple_bids ORDER BY bid DESC");
        while($bids = $bids_results->fetch_array()) {
          echo "<tr>\n\t<td>"
          . $bids['bid_volume']
          . "</td>\n\t<td>"
          . $bids['bid']
          . "</td>\n</tr>\n";
        }
        $bids_results->close();
     ?>
   </td>    
   <td>     
     <?php                          
       $offers_results = $mysqli->query("SELECT offer_volume, offer FROM apple_offers ORDER BY offer DESC");
       while($offers = $offers_results->fetch_array()) {
         echo "<tr>\n\t<td>"
         . $offers['offer']
         . "</td>\n\t<td>"
         . $offers['offer_volume']
         . "</td>\n</tr>\n" ;
       }
       $offers_results->close();
       $mysqli->close();    
     ?> 
   </td>  
 </tbody>
```

But for some reason the second table is presented below the first one. The same happens if I put the two `<td>` into one `<tr>` below the `<tbody>`

Comment: It looks like your table structure is invalid. Should go table > tbody > tr > td.  If nesting, you need to add all of these elements again. You cannot nest a tr directly under a td.

Comment: Ok, in this case I'd need to have two <tbody> next to each other. How can I do that?

Comment: Added an answer using your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really need to use `tbody` as that will be generated by the browser. With your code, the proper table structure would be something like the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <?php require_once "db_data.php"; $bids_results=$ mysqli->query("SELECT bid_volume, bid FROM apple_bids ORDER BY bid DESC"); while($bids = $bids_results->fetch_array()) { echo "            
                    <tr>
                        <td>" . $bids['bid_volume'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $bids['bid'] . "</td>
                    </tr>"; } $bids_results->close(); 
                ?>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <?php $offers_results=$ mysqli->query("SELECT offer_volume, offer FROM apple_offers ORDER BY offer DESC"); while($offers = $offers_results->fetch_array()) { echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>" . $offers['offer'] . "</td>
                        <td>" . $offers['offer_volume'] . "</td>
                    </tr>" ; } $offers_results->close(); $mysqli->close(); 
                 ?>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, dwreck08, we're coming closer. With your suggestion, the two tables are now displayed on top of each other.

Comment: Maybe you have styles on your table or your content is too much. Here is the same code without the PHP... http://jsfiddle.net/w08nzbyb/ Tables are side by side.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You were right. I had them styled. Thanks, very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this markup:

```html
<table>
     <tr>
          <td>
               <!-- PHP output here -->
          </td>
          <td>
               <!-- PHP output here -->
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```